# Facebook test user user_location permission for app review

Tags: facebook, facebook-permissions

I have a facebook app and I need to send it to app review. 
However, my app uses **user_location permission** and I need to provide information and steps regarding how my app uses location info.

The problem is, **Facebook does not allow to set location info for test users**. 
So how I can use a test user for the review process?
Should I create a real test user or is there any other way to set location info for the test user.

Thanks